# Pop up window gives an error on mdi form in C#

Tags: c#, mdi

I have a form that works fine on its own, but I want to add it to an `mdi` parent form.

The problem is that I have a small form that pops up, asks for info, then passes the info to the original form.

I use this to pop up the form:

```
Form2 fm = new Form2();

if (fm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

I get an error on the first line of `form2` (the pop up form):

```
Form1 fm2 = (Form1)this.Owner;

fm2.lbText = this.textBox1.Text;
```

Again, this all works fine if `form1` is a standalone form; but if I make it a child form I get this error when I click on OK on `form2` to return to `form1`.

> Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Partsbuddy2._0.Menu' to type 'Partsbuddy2._0.Form1'.

Answer (score 4):

this.Owner is apparently not the form but the Menu. Apparently one of the strange things that happen when you change to MDI

Instead of using the `Owner` property, you can add your own property to the `Form2`, containing the reference to the owner form:

```
public Form OwnerForm {get; set;}
```

and then when creating the new `Form2` instance, use:

```
Form2 fm = new Form2() { OwnerForm = this };
```

and in the `Form2` you use this to access `Form1`:

```
Form1 fm2 = (Form1)this.OwnerForm;
```